# Property 'x' does not exist on type 'unknown'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-router

I'm not quite getting this. I scoured through stackoverflow and github, and one of the solutions I tried was to add a generic but I'm getting this error `Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.` under `useLocation<LocationState>` Here is my code below. The problem I'm having is setting types to `{searchvalue}` but its an unknown type. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

interface SearchResultsProps {}

interface LocationState {
    serachValue: string
}

export const SearchResults: React.FC<SearchResultsProps> = ({}) => {

    const location = useLocation<LocationState>();

     const {searchValue} = location.state
    

  return <div>Results Page</div>;
```

Comment: useLocation is not generic. Please show you code for useLocation.

Comment: @windowsill thats the whole code. useLocation is imported from react router

Comment: The import is added now. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a link to the documentation for the `useLocation` hook from `react-router-dom`: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#uselocation

It defines the function signature as:

> ```ts
> declare function useLocation(): Location;
>
> interface Location extends Path {
>   state: unknown;
>   key: Key;
> }
> ```

You can see that `location.state` is of type `unknown`, so if you have pushed data into the history state, and want to access it in a type-safe way, you can [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) the type of data that you have pushed into the state like this:

```ts
const location = useLocation();
const {serachValue} = location.state as LocationState;
```

Here's a complete example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCYFMBmBDArgG3hgZzgCUUMBjGAGjhgE8wUSzKBRHFEFAOxgF84aKBBBwA5FBYwxAbgBQoSLERYCKADIRyGGMAjcBQkeMkUYAWmFYYKKOaQjZcufUZxW4egHkARgCsUSjgAXmZyaCQAHm4UADdbGhj4qAA+eVcmTW1dfQBlGB0mUIQ4NSgKAAsANQwcLBQALlKYKGBuAHMZOD55OTQsbko9bjhcsihyCtICXBgiAAowYTACJo8wb39AmABKJtIzdk4eeAQ5ODhw7gJ4HC0dYZC4VQ17nO55nfkLq5vEMsqNTqKAEoTu2WGADoboU4IQ4FkHnkCjZvnBJDAsFARvNIkhgLEUtNZkQAAoYdooSIAenxhK+cj4ciAA)

```ts
import {default as React, type ReactElement} from 'react';
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';

type EmptyObject = Record<never, never>;
type LocationState = { serachValue: string; };

function SearchResults (props: EmptyObject): ReactElement {
  const location = useLocation();
  const {serachValue} = location.state as LocationState;
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^
// is now type 'string'
  return (<div>Results Page</div>);
}
```

Comment: got it. I saw this solution from github but someone mentioned ```yeah but then you opt out of any compile time type safety by doing as { from: string }``` so maybe there was a better way of doing it. Anywho, thanks!

Comment: The reason that it needs to be asserted is that you can push arbitrary data into every history state entry, so typing it as just one type would be inflexible, but requiring consumers to provide the correct type (potentially an extremely large union) would be inconvenient/impractical.

Answer (score 1):

`useLocation` isn't generically [typed](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L400-L409).

```
export function useLocation(): Location {
  invariant(
    useInRouterContext(),
    // TODO: This error is probably because they somehow have 2 versions of the
    // router loaded. We can help them understand how to avoid that.
    `useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.`
  );

  return React.useContext(LocationContext).location;
}
```

Remove the `<LocationState>` and type the return value.

Example:

```
const { state }: { state: LocationState } = useLocation();
```

Comment: "_`useLocation` isn't typed_": `useLocation` is typed, but [`Location.state` is `unknown`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71389676/438273)

Comment: @jsejcksn Oops, I meant it's not generically typed. Good catch. OP's issue isn't necessarily that `state` is an unknown type though. They are trying to type the `useLocation` hook.